# Could not load file or assembly XXX or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-assembly

When running an Asp.Net MVC application locally, everything runs fine but when application is deployed on the server, I am getting this error.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'WebGrease, Version=1.5.1.25624, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I have just recently added the `System.Web.Optimization` framework through NuGet which makes use of WebGrease.

If I check references, my version of WebGrease is 1.5.2.14234 which is higher than the one complaining about not finding - 1.5.1.25624.

Within the root web config, I have the following underneath the runtime tag:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

If I check the WebGrease.dll within the bin folder on the server, the version of the WebGrease DLL is 1.5.2.14234.  Who could be requiring the other version 1.5.1.25624 and any idea how this can be solved?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It was a mistake from our end whereby the actual root web config on the server had an incorrect `dependentAssembly` tag which consisted of:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.3.0.0" newVersion="1.3.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

and not:

```
<dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234" />
      </dependentAssembly>
```

hence why the error was being issued!

Comment: This was also my problem. On my side, during publish, it is on the web config transform because the server and my PC's dll has different version (I put the code above on <runtime>, and bindingRedirect newVersion). I just unchecked the precompile option because the old dll is only present on the server, in order to proceed to publish.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error come up with my project as well. It turns out that there were several "XYZ-Copy.dll"'s in my bin directory that was causing the problem. I deleted all XYZ-copy.dll files and it worked.

Comment: bahhh, i hate stuff like this.  I added a project to a cloud backup service and it created a duplicate .dll in my bin directory.  Thanks for the hint in the right direction.

Comment: Happy to help out! These little one off issues drive me nuts!

Answer (score 2):

i just deleted everything in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET\
its working ... if u r using framework 4 then try C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Comment: Thanks for your comment but as described in my previous answer, this was resolved due to an error within the web.config file as ex explained.

Comment: Of a more general nature (not associated with "WebGrease") this error can happen if your app pool is started without 32 bit enabled, then you change it to enabled.  This answer fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I tried installing the latest version from Nuget:

```
 install-package WebGrease
```

ReBuild the application twice and the error went away.

hope it help somebody!

Answer (score 1):

This was resolved by

1) running the Package Manager Console

2) in Console, type: 'Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization'

Which resolved all the incorrect dependencies and Successfully added [Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/) to the Project